# Fuzzing Android API

Tags: mobile, android, fuzzing

I am thinking of trying to make an Android API fuzzer (I never made a fuzzer before, but I understand the concepts), and I was wondering which API calls would be the most interesting ones to fuzz from the security point of view? I think probably SQL, communication and networking stuff would be the place to start but I was wondering if there are any specific ones that I should pay attention to?

Comment: I'd suggest playing around with something a little more accessible first. An Android fuzzer requires you to write a lot of code that talks to the target device, which makes the process quite a bit more complex.

Comment: @Polynomial - would it be plausible to create a fuzzer as an android app, and monitor the output of fuzzing through adb->logcat (android debug bridge (shell))? I thought that would give me the right kind of access to what the fuzzer would output.

Comment: Yes, that's a viable solution. However, you're still going to need to capture the fault and dig through for info. I'm not telling you *not* to try it, I'm just saying it might be a good idea to try something local (e.g. Windows / Linux) first.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project building android fuzzers from the polytechnic institute of Singapore here: http://androidfuzzing.com/

Have a look what they are doing.

Comment: At the time of writing the link is not working.